# How to join in sql with multiple tables (need) join multiple references?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, join

Some table only have identity columns but this is because this is a example only.

```
create table producto(
idproducto int identity primary key
)

create table inventario(
idInventario id int identity primary key,
idproducto int,
foreign key (idproducto) references producto(idproducto)
)

create table sucursal(
idSucursal id int identity primary key
)

create table inventariosucursal(
idinventariosucursal id int primary key,
idsucursal int,
idinventario int,
foreign key (idsucursal) references sucursal (idsucursal),
foreign key (idinventario) references inventario (idinventario),
)

create table mejoresventasxsucursal
(
mejoresventasxsucursal id int primary key,
idsucursal int,
idproducto int,
foreign key (idsucursal) references sucursal(idsucursal),
foreign key (idproducto) references producto (idproducto)
)
```

What do I need?

select the stocking ( inventario table ) by every branch office (sucursal table) but only most selled products (mejoresventasxsucursal table).

the problem is mejoresventasxsucursal  table does "join" with 2 tables product and sucursal but after i have other table with does "join" with same 2 tables product and sucursal.

```
select s.id,i.id,p.id,
from producto p
join inventario i on p.idproducto = i.idproducto
join inventariosucursal i_s on i_s.idinventario = i.idinventario
join sucursal s on i_s on i_s.idsucursal = s.idsucursal
join producto p on i.producto = p.idproducto
join mejoresventasxsucursal mv on mv.idsucursal = s.idsucursal
```

Here is the problem. I need join mejoresventasxsucursal with producto. I know I could do something as join producto p2 but I would like to know what is the best way for join with producto. I know other solution is in where condition doing where p.idproducto=mv.idprocucto

Comment: Why do you have multiple tables with nothing more than an identity?

Comment: @SeanLange this is for example only

Comment: @angel so why can't you join mejoresventasxsucursal mv on mv.idsucursal = s.idsucursal and mv.idproducto = p.idproducto or am i missing the point?

Comment: @Chris Believe the result set is not the same, i have checked with some queries. other soluction is doing ->> join sucursal s2 on s2.idsucursal=s.idsucursal and (doing the join i needed) but i dont know if this  have a bad performance doing join again to the same table.

Comment: Please don't use all caps.

Comment: @angel the result sets are bound to be different, the real question is do you need the mejoresventasxsucursal  - whatever they are - that are linked to producto and inventario  OR do you need the mejoresventasxsucursal  information for the producto

Comment: ^ OR do you need the mejoresventasxsucursal information for the inventario

Comment: I need linked to producto and inventario per sucursal (product and stocking per branch)

Comment: @angel so i believe that the join should be the following:   mejoresventasxsucursal mv on mv.idsucursal = s.idsucursal and mv.idproducto = p.idproducto -- the note you added about joining onto sucursal again doesn't make sense as the 2nd join won't fix the problem with your join onto mejoresventasxsucursal

Comment: that is a solution, but is it ok doing it? because (if this was a large query using a lot of joins) this would be difficult to found with what table i did the join because (in this time) it was the first table..

Comment: @angel again, what do you mean xD - You should be able to tell me if doing that is fine, I don't know your database structure ideally it should probably be a composite key join that makes sense with what data you want to return.